# Why my Attribute group is persisted in all attributesets?

Tags: magento2

i have the following code :

```
 $categorySetup = $this->categorySetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);
        $attributeSet = $this->attributeSetFactory->create();
        $entityTypeId = $categorySetup->getEntityTypeId(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY);
        $attributeSetId = $categorySetup->getDefaultAttributeSetId($entityTypeId, 'medicamento_expira_curta2');
        $autosettingsTabName = 'medicamento_expira_curta2_group';
        $categorySetup->addAttributeGroup($entityTypeId, $attributeSetId, $autosettingsTabName, 60);
        $data = [
            'attribute_set_name' => 'medicamento_expira_curta2', 
            'entity_type_id' => $entityTypeId,
            'sort_order' => 200,
        ];
        $attributeSet->setData($data);
        $attributeSet->validate();
        $attributeSet->save();
        $attributeSet->initFromSkeleton($attributeSetId);
        $attributeSet->save();

        $eavSetup = $this->eavSetupFactory->create(['setup' => $setup]);   

        $eavSetup->addAttributeGroup(
            $entityTypeId, 
            $attributeSet = $attributeSetId , 
            'medicamento_expira_curta2_group', 
            200
        );


        $eavSetup->removeAttribute(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,'medicamento_expira_curta2');
        $eavSetup->addAttribute(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Product::ENTITY,  'medicamento_expira_curta2',   /* Custom Attribute Code */
            [
                'group' => 'medicamento_expira_curta_group2',/* Group name in which you want 
                                              to display your custom attribute */
                'type' => 'int',/* Data type in which formate your value save in database*/
                'backend' => '',
                'frontend' => '',
                'label' => 'DATATESTESCOPED2', /* lablel of your attribute*/
                'input' => 'date',
                'class' => '',
                // 'source' => 'ModuleNameSpace\YourModuleName\Model\Config\Source\Options',
                                /* Source of your select type custom attribute options*/
                'global' => \Magento\Eav\Model\Entity\Attribute\ScopedAttributeInterface::SCOPE_GLOBAL,
                                    /*Scope of your attribute */
                'visible' => true,
                'required' => true,
                'user_defined' => true,
                'default' => '',
                'searchable' => false,
                'filterable' => false,
                'comparable' => false,
                'visible_on_front' => false,
                'used_in_product_listing' => true,
                'unique' => false,
                'attribute_set_id' => 'medicamento_expira_curta2'
            ]
        );
```

The attribute is allowed to the correct attribute set, but the group, is persisted in all attributesets, i miss any configuration ?

Answer (score 0):

Please check the following:

- All the attribute sets you have created are dependent on the
  **`Default`** attribute sets.
- You are adding the new attribute group to the **`Default`** attribute set.

If yes, all the attribute sets will have the new attribute group as part.

If you want to assign the attribute group to a particular attribute set only, then either assign the attribute group to a non-default attribute set.

<s>Or, create the custom attribute sets as non-dependent on the default attribute set.</s>

Comment: You can show me an example for adding the attribute group not assing to the default ?

Comment: Sorry, I have updated my answer. There is no way from the admin panel to do so.

Comment: programatically ?

Comment: I just checked whether a new attribute set can be independent or not. I found that apart from the default attribute set, all other attribute sets must have a value for **`Based On`**. So, I think there is no way to create an attribute set which is independent of the default attribute set.